# Wordpress - dot before hover Item

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system

The problem is that I have a task to make a white dot when the item menu is hover . ( picture below) . I am asking for help, because it is very important for my order. If need be, I'll pay.

Page is on draft : dalaindustrisupport.shapehosting.se

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89hYn.jpg)

I'm not good in CSS codes. Usually taking stock settings of plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
}
li:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hover Here</li>
</ul>
```